# Why I can't set my form height to 30px?

Tags: c#, forms, height

I tried set that, but when this, my Form still have greater height. Is any way to do this?

Comment: Windows Forms? Show some code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make ControlBox=False; and you will get what you want. Because it is ControlBox have size more than 30x30, without it you can do all size.

Comment: Yes, now Form have 30px height. Thank to your help, now I finished my work!

Answer (score 2):

[A Note from MSDN:-](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx)

> With the Sizable style, it is impossible to resize the window below a
>   certain minimum value, even if you have set ControlBox to false and
>   assigned a zero-length string to Text. Consider working around this by
>   using the [`SizableToolWindow style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx) instead.

Comment: I'm using FormBorderStyle=none. It is very important for me. Is any other way to do this?

Comment: Not sure,but msdn writes it as impossible.May be there can be other ways to do it, perhaps using native APIs like CreateWindowEx.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have set `true` to `Form.AutoSize` property. Turn off  the `AutoSize=false`.

Comment: I set to false but Form height still large

Comment: We don't know what properties of `Form` are set or not. Try to create a new `Form` and see what happen.

Comment: I recognized that because FormBorderStyle=none. If I change this, my Form have 30px height. But FormBorderStyle=none is important for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that the problom is the border style
all forms have a border the you cant change 
if you dont mind having no border just set the border style to none and then the form height can be even 0px

Comment: I set FormBorderStyle to none but my Form height still large

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works for me.

In your class derived from Form, override two methods to bypass the size correction that is applied and that forbid you to set sizes below the limitation.

```
    // the *real* width and height of your form, Width and Height are now lying...
    internal int CoreWidth { get; private set; }
    internal int CoreHeight { get; private set; }

    // just for fun :
    public new int Width { get { return CoreWidth; } }
    public new int Height { get { return CoreHeight; } }

    protected override void SetClientSizeCore ( int x, int y )
    {
        // get wished width and height earlier enough in the chain of calls
        CoreWidth = x;
        CoreHeight = y;
        base.SetClientSizeCore ( x, y );
    }

    protected override void SetBoundsCore ( int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified )
    {
        // don't trust width and height that are provided, use the ones you kept
        base.SetBoundsCore ( x, y, CoreWidth, CoreHeight, specified );
    }
```

Worked like a charm... I using that to create some kind of notification windows that pop anywhere on the screen, that can contains any kind of control and have any size, with no limitation.